Why do some installers insist on not doing a full frame window replacement?
We're replacing a few windows in our old 1920s house. The windows are original and the wood frame on one of them has had water intrusion through the frame. We even had a water bubble last year that we're pretty sure came from water through the rotten frame.
We had someone come out who specialized in restoring these old wooden windows (was too expensive), and he said if we ever did replace them to make sure we did a full-frame installation because the originals had no flashing and he saw the water damage.
We've had about 5 companies look at these so far and more than half of them have said we don't need a full-frame replacement and just want to do a retrofit. It's obviously cheaper to retrofit but we're wary of doing that to only continue having water intrusion issues afterwards. Are we overly concerned about this?



Because it's not just installing windows, but usually involves replacing framing members, reflashing, dealing with siding, etc. Requires an actual skilled craftsman as opposed to a crew leader with some helpers. It's also hard to estimate, because one doesn't know the extent of the job until the windows are removed. Then, if one finds rotten framing or other issues, when asking for more money to do these repairs, the client feels one is holding them hostage while they have a house exposed to the elements. So craftsmen/contractors willing to go through this are few and expensive.

One issue with finding contractors for old homes is that newer homes tend to be more standardized. Old homes are 'like a box of chocolates'.  You are more likely to find surprises when you open up a wall in an old house. Homes were built to different standards that few people remember. What you learn working on 20-year-old houses doesn't necessarily apply when working on a 100-year-old house.

@JimmyJames Indeed, and it's not just standardization but also all the history of fixes and improvements the house has accumulated. As someone who lives in a 100-year-old house that has been through several complete remodels over the time, I can confirm that there's always a surprise waiting in the walls. Any modification, no matter how trivial it seems it should be, turns into a bit of an archaeology project, leading to discoveries like "oh this is where a gas line used to run in the 1930s".

@TooTea Usually for me it is weird electrical. I once found an old cloth wrapped wire with seven or so solid 14-guage wires strands running around the perimeter of my house. It took me a while to track it around and find it wasn't connected to anything.

Because it's fast, easy, and profitable to do it that way.
Those companies pay low wages to questionably skilled installers to swoop in, slap some plastic windows in place with low-grade trim fitment, and swoop out. That's how they make a buck.
They'll never enter my house.
You can do windows yourself. You need to learn about some or all of these things to be successful (which is precisely why full replacement is more expensive):

Window types (new construction vs. retrofit--you may do better with the former)
Fitment (rough openings, framing)
Working on elevated structures (scaffolding, ladders)
Demolition
Siding and exterior trim repair
Installation (positioning, squaring, fastening)
Weather sealing and insulation
Interior trim


We've had several windows replaced in our old house, and we had them all done by a general contractor (who we knew and trusted).  A window "expert" isn't necessary, but someone who can handle any "surprises" that crop up is definitely a good idea (as mentioned above).

It also depends whether or not you want to match the character of the old windows and are willing to pay the freight to make that happen.

Add "dry weather" to the requirements for success :)   Source, lived in a house with quake damage over several winters.

2 of the 3: fast, good, or cheap. Exterior of the house is stucco, so 'cheap' is right out. We just finished 74 leaded glass steel frame windows, c. 1920. There's two companies in the country that do that, both of which are six months out, minimum, and wanted half a million dollars. We came in at slightly under half that. You can definitely do them yourself if you have 30y exp working with your hands... and a blank check.
